# Odd behavior in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

Open the link in Stackblitz

https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples

Replace value="Sushi" with [(ngModel)]="Sushi"

No change in UI

Replace with [(ngModel)]="food.Sushi" where I want to implement with class.

UI looks different. Underline is not appearing

[image: No Underline]

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t an Angular Material issue, this is a basic JavaScript issue. If you examined the console when you tried `[(ngModel)]="food.Sushi"` on the default Angular Material input StackBlitz, you would see the error:

```
Error: Cannot read property 'Sushi' of undefined
```

This error is preventing the input from rendering properly. You would need to at minimum define a property on the component class `food` of type `any` with a default value of an empty object `{}` so that the desired object sub-property `food.Sushi` can be set by `ngModel` when the user interacts with the input.

Component (metadata comes from `mat-input` StackBlitz example):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  styleUrls: ['input-overview-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
})
export class InputOverviewExample {
  food: any = {};
}
```

Template (don't forget `name` property):

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" name="food" [(ngModel)]="food.Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dughda) in action. With the default value of an empty object set for class property `food`, the input renders correctly because the error from the console is resolved.

Hopefully that helps!